# Update FigureCanvasQTAgg canvas using Figure() object

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the GUI which has an main window with button and FigureCanvasQTAgg canvas with defaul plot(just some default scatter dots). Button click command should change the canvas using Figure() object as argument. I'm wonder how to construct such function that will receive Figure() object and update canvas. The tutorials always deal with update functions that create figure by itself, but in my case such update function should receive figure (that was calculated outside the GUI class) as argument. Below you can see my (maybe pseudo) code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRunnable, QThreadPool
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import queue as Queue

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

import os, sys
import psutil

# Back up the reference to the exceptionhook
sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

def my_exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
    # Print the error and traceback
    print(exctype, value, traceback)
    # Call the normal Exception hook after
    sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
    sys.exit(1)

# Set the exception hook to our wrapping function
sys.excepthook = my_exception_hook

def create_graph():

    ax = Figure().add_subplot ( 111 )
    ax.plot ( [1 , 2 , 3 , 4] , [10 , 20 , 25 , 30] , color = 'lightblue' , linewidth = 3 )

    return ax

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self , queue):
        QRunnable.__init__ ( self )
        self.queue = queue

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):

        ax = create_graph()
        self.queue.put ( ax )  ### transport ax object to GUI class

class Canvas ( FigureCanvas ):

    def __init__(self, parent, figure):

        self.fig = figure
        FigureCanvas.__init__ ( self , self.fig )
        self.setParent ( parent )

class GUI (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1800, 900)
        MainWindow.move(40,20)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

        self.fig , axes = plt.subplots ( 1 , 1 )
        plt.scatter ( [0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5] , [3 , 11 , 15 , 0 , 1 , 19] )
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, self.fig)

        self.canvas.setGeometry ( QtCore.QRect ( 30 , 400 , 811 , 381 ) )

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.startButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 310, 261, 51))
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startCalc)
        self.startButton.setText('Press me to redraw graph')

    def startCalc(self):

            self.queue = Queue.Queue ()
            self.threadpool = QThreadPool ()
            print ( "Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount () )
            worker = Worker (self.queue)
            self.threadpool.start ( worker )

            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot ( 500 , self.process_queue )

    def process_queue(self):
        try:
            msg = self.queue.get ( 0 ) ### here we have our ax object

            self.fig.clear()

            # Here I dont know how to re-draw self.canvas widget with new data (ax)
            #Usualy one should create ax object right before canvas.draw function, but I have my ax object returned from outside the GUI class ... :((
            self.canvas.draw ()

        except Queue.Empty:
            # print('empty')
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot ( 500 , self.process_queue )

def main():
    global window
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication ( sys.argv )  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = GUI ()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show ()  # Показываем окно
    try:
        sys.exit ( app.exec_ () )
    except:
        print ( "Exiting" )

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main ()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc add reproducible example